# .NET console application: how to get user input while constantly logging to console?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, .net-6.0

A .NET (Core) console application provides extensive console logging. At certain points the application needs user input, while still logging.

**Problem**: Unfortunately the flowing log pushes the input text and prompt up so the user cannot see it anymore. They can still enter something and press Return - which works - but it's utterly unintuitive.

How to solve this? I saw that PowerShell Core allows to show a progress bar "above" the log output using [Write-Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.2). Could this be something?

In a first step I need a solution for Windows. For other platforms I already use means like [Zenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) to get user input. (Providing an interactive prompt on Windows seems to be a bigger challenge than I hoped. But that's another topic.)

So how can I solve my problem: gathering user input in a console application while constantly logging output to the console window?

Comment: From the link you provided, it seems that Zenity should work on Windows too.

Comment: Just my 2 cents but why use a console application when you require UI? Can the inputs be passed as command line parameters, eliminating the run-time UI? Otherwise, consider promoting this to a GUI application (WPF, UWP, WinForms, etc).

Comment: @phuzi I'd like to use something that is readily available on a platform.

Comment: @ScottWelker Good points. Among the inputs is a secret, at least for that the command line param is no option. So far I hoped to stay within the bounds of a command line application and wanted to check the options. If there is no good solution I might resort to promoting this to a GUI app, or maybe to consider phuzi 's input and add instructions for a third party GUI app like Zenity on Windows.

Comment: A sneaky workaround I've done in the past is use threading and mutexes to keep my output in the top three lines of the console and input fairly centred in the console.

You can use Console.SetCursorPosition for this